# Как получить имя роута в Slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

Как получить имя исполняемого роута в PHP фреймфорке Slim  v3.*?

Пробовал через `\Slim\Router`. Методов подходящих не нашел. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно [это](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Route.php#L148) Вам должно помочь.

Comment: Я не могу получить сам экземпляр этого `\Slim\Route`.

Comment: Если у Вас есть $request можете попробовать сделать так: 
`$routeInfo = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo');  
$router = $this->container->get('router');
$route = $router->lookupRoute($routeInfo[1]);
$name = $route->getName(); `

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемой, что в `Middleware` получить имя роута, который подходит под входящий url у меня не получалось.
Дело решалось установкой в настройках при запуске приложения ключа `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` в значение `true`.

Тогда приложение перед запуском `Middleware` ищет, под какой роут подходит url и его можно получить как раз тем образом, который вы описали.